# Elasticsearch - search for keys inside nested field value, which is a json

Tags: elasticsearch

I needed some help with a query that I trying to execute.

I have a field called scores inside one of my indexes which stores some ai model scores for as a `json`. The basic structure of this field is like (showing a couple of records from the index):

```
[{"scores":
    {"a/b": 1.231,
     "a/c": 23.11,
     "x/a": 1232.1}},
 {"scores":
    {"a/d": 3.1}}]
```

And the mapping is something like:

```
{"scores":
  {"properties":
    {"a/b": {"type":"float"},
     "a/c": {"type":"float"},
     "a/d": {"type":"float"}}}}
```

The value for the field scores, which is another `json` will have arbitrary fields i.e. I won't know which fields are present in that `json` beforehand.

What I want to do is to search for the keys inside that `json` i.e. if I search for `a/`, it should return ["a/b", "a/d", "a/c"].

I know this is possible via nested query, but looks like for that I'll need to re-map my indexes, so that the field scores has a flatter data structure. However I didn't want to do that for now and just wanted to use the existing structure and execute my query.

If anyone has ideas about this, kindly throw them my way.

Comment: So what's the current mapping then?

Comment: @JoeSorocin I updated the question with the mapping.

Comment: OK but it's still unclear what you want to achieve... Are you building a query and want to target only the `a/`-prefixed fields?

Comment: @JoeSorocin Exactly, I want to get the fields starting with `a/`.

Comment: What does “get fields” mean?

Comment: Return them in the response without querying them?

Comment: @JoeSorocin Yes, I do want to query them. For ex, I want the fields (and probably their values) inside the `scores` field which start with the string `"a/"`. I want to build a query like this. Whether or not the results are filtered (i.e. only the fields that start with `"a/"`) is not that much of a concern, but I just want the query to match the relevant results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `_source` to limit what's retrieved:

```
POST indexname/_search
{
 "_source": "scores.a/*"
}
```

Alternatively, you could employ `script_fields` which do exactly the same but offer playroom for value modification too:

```
POST indexname/_search
{
  "script_fields": {
   "scores_prefixed_with_a": {
     "script": {
       "source": """params._source.scores.entrySet()
                        .stream()
                        .filter(e->e.getKey().startsWith(params.prefix))
                        .collect(Collectors.toMap(e->e.getKey(),e->e.getValue()))""",
       "params": {
         "prefix": "a/"
       }
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Comment: Yes it did. I had to slightly modify the query, which I was supposed to post here an an edit to your answer. But for some reason it's saying that the suggestion queue is full.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) - [`.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) on [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```js
const data = [{"scores": {"a/b": 1.231, "a/c": 23.11, "x/a": 1232.1}}, {"scores": {"a/d": 3.1}}];

const allowed = 'a/';

const res = data.map((d) => 
    Object.keys(d.scores)
    .filter(key => key.startsWith(allowed)))
    .reduce((prev, curr) => prev.concat(curr)); 

console.log(res)
```

```
[
  "a/b",
  "a/c",
  "a/d"
]
```

---

---

Originial, with object instead off keys;

```js
const data = [{"scores": {"a/b": 1.231, "a/c": 23.11, "x/a": 1232.1}}, {"scores": {"a/d": 3.1}}];

const allowed = 'a/';

const res = data.map((d) => 
  Object.keys(d.scores)
    .filter(key => key.startsWith(allowed))
    .reduce((obj, key) => { obj[key] = d.scores[key]; return obj; }, {})); 
console.log(res);
```